# Running Processes that Pipe to each other shares Thread (core)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I noticed when doing some Decoding / Encoding with 2 process that feed each other data through piping, that both would share the same thread, so basically they both runt at 50%.

Now the procceses are both created on a separate thread to begin with, so i though.
Well I can just make another thread and let it create one of the proccesses, that should make both run on 2 threads right.

Well doesn't seem to help.

Here is how it's setup in a nutshell.

```
//This code is withing one private void that's run on it's own thread
cmdCommands = new Process();
cmdCommands.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmdCommands.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdCommands.StartInfo.FileName = SC.GetAVS2PipeModPath();
cmdCommands.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} \"{1}\" -wav", SC.GetAVS2PipeModPath(), filename + ".avs");
cmdCommands.Start();
ThreadStart TS = new ThreadStart(() =>OpusThread(filename));
Thread TT = new Thread(TS);
TT.Start();

cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096, PipeWrite, null);
cmdCommands.WaitForExit();
```

---

```
//This should be started on another thread as you can see above where it's created
private void OpusThread(string filename)
{
    OpusEncoder = new Process();
    OpusEncoder.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    OpusEncoder.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    OpusEncoder.StartInfo.FileName = SC.GetOpusEncPath();
    OpusEncoder.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} - \"{1}\"", SC.GetOpusSettings(true), @"C:\Users\The Curator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MuxEncoder\MuxEncoder\bin\Release\testinasd" + ".opus");
    OpusEncoder.Start();

    OpusEncoder.WaitForExit();
}
```

Though both still share the same thread as far as i can see from the utilizing.

Here is the Pipe operation, it continuously writes the data achieved from Process 1 to Processes 2. This seems to be what cases a "link" that makes them share thread.

```
    private void PipeWrite(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int read = cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);

        if(read!=0)
        {
            OpusEncoder.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096);

            //OpusEncoder.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush();
            Outfile2.Write(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096);
            Outfile2.Flush();
        }
        cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096, PipeWrite, null);
    }
```

Comment: What's your system's processor/core configuration? Dual? Quad?

Comment: Quad , so utilizing is 25%, so they are both at 12-13%

Comment: If the overall CPU utilization is at 25% that does not mean each process is taking up half of that. It might be that one of them is fully using one core while the other one is stalled for some reason. Have you checked the task manager?

Comment: @Tudor Yes i have. Worth mentioning is, this seems to occur when i "connect" them, through pipe. If i do 2 separate works with the processes, they will run at max speed.

Comment: Have you also checked their CPU affinity? Maybe they're both set to only run on a single core for some reason.

Comment: @Tudor Yes done. But as said, it only appears when i pipe. Will change my topic for that, as it's misleading.

Comment: Hmmm so far I suspect the programs are locked in a sequential read-write relationship since I can't see any buffering taking place. So essentially one process is producing a result and sending it to the other one, but the second process is always stuck waiting for the first one to produce something, thus there is no parallel execution.

Comment: @Tudor probably. They are locked in that Async call. I am thinking of letting that run alone and put the file in a Queue, and have another thread process it to see if that has any impact.

Comment: What you can do is have an array of say 10000 pieces of 4096 bytes (you can use a `BlockingCollection`) and have the first process writing to it while the second one keeps reading.

Comment: @Tudor actually what i am trying now, the Blocking Collection. Seems to work, just need a way to tell it when it's over (no more data).

Comment: I suppose there should be some special end of stream token you can send.

Comment: @Tudor yeah just not sure how to use it, as i never have used them. But will look for it, can't be that hard to use the "CancellationToken"

Answer (score 1):

Okay basically it's what Tudor and i noticed.
The processes using the same thread to communicate, and therefore they can't go faster than the counterpart, they are simply sharing a thread.

So to solve this i used the BlockingCollection (Damn this thing is handy), and here is the solution.

```
    //The Process running in it's own thread,
    //Always looking for new data until it receives and empty byte[].
    private void OpusEncode(string filename)
    {
        using (OpusEncoder = new Process())
        {
            OpusEncoder.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            OpusEncoder.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            OpusEncoder.StartInfo.FileName = SC.GetOpusEncPath();
            OpusEncoder.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} - \"{1}\"", SC.GetOpusSettings(true), filename + ".opus");
            OpusEncoder.Start();

            byte[] temp;

            while (QU.TryTake(out temp, Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                if (temp.Length == 0)
                    break;
                OpusEncoder.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);

            }
            OpusEncoder.StandardInput.Close();
            OpusEncoder.WaitForExit();
        }                 
    }


       //The Pipe callback which binds the two processes
       //I am basically feeding the Queue clones (Important!)
       //And when it's at the end of the stream, send an Empty byte[]
       private void PipeWrite(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int read = cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);

        if (read != 0)
        {
            QU.Add((byte[])ReadBuffer.Clone());
            cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096, PipeWrite, null);
        }
        else
        {
            ReadBuffer = new byte[0];
            QU.Add(ReadBuffer);

            cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Close();
        }

    }


      //Here is just how they are called, this is also a separate thread
                    cmdCommands.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cmdCommands.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    cmdCommands.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cmdCommands.StartInfo.FileName = SC.GetAVS2PipeModPath();
                    cmdCommands.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} \"{1}\" -wav", SC.GetAVS2PipeModPath(), filename + ".avs");
                    cmdCommands.Start();

                    Thread OpusThread = new Thread(() => OpusEncode(filename));
                    OpusThread.Start();

                    cmdCommands.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 4096, PipeWrite, null);
                    cmdCommands.WaitForExit();
```

If anyone noticed anything wrong here, or something that can be improved please tell, as i am quite unsure how it all fit together.

For example, using an empty byte[] as a "notifier" doesn't seem like the best idea, but it works.